# Cambiar item seleccionado en NavigationView cuando cambio el fragment

Tags: android, botón, fragment, navigationview

buenos dias. Estoy con un problema en cual tengo la plantilla NavigationView generada por Android Studio, los items de la barra de navegacion estan asociados a un fragment, el desplazamineto entre los fragment usando la barra de navegacion funciona bien, pero cuando quiero cambiar con un boton que está en uno de esos fragments a otro fragment, el item seleccionado en la barra de navegacion no se actualiza y sigue apuntando al primer fragment.

Para pasar de un fragment a otro uso:

```
 btnResultados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fragmentResultados = new resultados();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedorPrincipal, fragmentResultados);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

El cambio de fragment lo hace bien, pero no se actualiza el item seleccionado en la barra de navegacion.

Comment: Tenés que generar un método que se llame FragmentTransaction, y esto es lo que hace las transiciones. Suerte!

Comment: Gracias Nocturno, pero en realidad la respuesta que necesitaba era:

Principal.navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);

Comment: Saludos @LucasDiaz, por favor publica y acepta tu propia respuesta. Así otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema podrán encontrar tu aporte. Lee este **[enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)** para mas información.